# Limit of ratio of integrals that go to zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I am working on a statistical problem and trying to understand how to compute

$$
R = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^t x^a (1-x)^b \sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}}\exp\left(- \frac{n}{v}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\right)\,dx}{\int_{0}^1 x^a (1-x)^b \sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}} \exp\left(- \frac{n}{v}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\right)\,dx},
$$
for $a, b > -1$, $v>0$ and $0 < t < 1$ arbitrary.

I've looked at several resources that discuss when and how one can interchange the limit and integration operations, but here my $f_n$ converge to $0$ and I don't know how to deal with that. I appreciate any insights into how to compute this particular limit, as well as similar limits where the integrand goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Some scratch work tells me that $R=t^{a+\frac{3}{2}}$, but I'm not sure if it's justified.

Comment: I suggest changing the integration variable $x$ to $y = (n/v)*x/(1+x)$. After making this substitution, take the limit of $n$ to infinity. You can then perform the two integrations.

Comment: Because of the exp terms in both integrands, it looks like the integrals are dominated by the values of x near 0.  In that case, the ratio would $\to 1$.

Comment: I do think the limit is $1$. The question is how to make a rigorous argument that is true.

Comment: Use L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @Prasiortle I just don't know exactly how to do that.

Comment: Well, you'll need to differentiate both integrals with respect to $n$. Leibniz's rule (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment: not a rigorous proof, but just some heuristic considerations.

$R = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\int_{0}^t x^a (1-x)^b \sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}}\exp\left(- \frac{n}{v}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\right)\,dx}{\int_{0}^1 x^a (1-x)^b \sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x}} \exp\left(- \frac{n}{v}\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)\right)\,dx}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(1)}{(2)}$

Let's also denote $m=\frac{n}{v}\to\infty$.

Making change in (1) $x=ts$

$$(1)=t^{a+3/2}\int_0^1s^a(1-st)^b\sqrt{\frac{s}{1+st}}e^{-m\frac{st}{1+st}}ds$$
Making another change $ms=x$
$$(1)=t^{a+3/2}m^{-a-3/2}\int_0^mx^a(1-\frac{t}{m}x)^b\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+xt/m}}e^{-\frac{xt}{1+xt/m}}dx$$
First, we can expand integration to $\infty$ (up to exponentially small terms $\sim e^{-mt}$).

We also note that at $xt\sim \sqrt m \,\,\,\,e^{-xt}\sim e^{-\sqrt m}\ll1 $ and $\frac{xt}{m}\ll1$. Therefore, we can expand the integrand into the Taylor series:
$$(1)\sim t^{a+3/2}m^{-a-3/2}\int_0^\infty x^{a+1/2}\big(1-\frac{bt}{m}x+O(1/m^2)\big)\big(1-\frac{t}{2m}x+O(1/m^2)\big)e^{-xt}e^{(xt)^2/m+O(1/m^2)}dx$$
Expanding $e^{(xt)^2/m+O(1/m^2)}=1+(xt)^2/m+O(1/m^2)$
$$(1)\sim t^{a+3/2}m^{-a-3/2}\int_0^\infty x^{a+1/2}\Big(1-(\frac{bt}{m}+\frac{t}{2m})x+\frac{x^2t^2}{m}+O(1/m^2)\Big)e^{-xt}dx$$
$$=t^{a+3/2}m^{-a-3/2}\int_0^\infty x^{a+1/2}\Big(1-\frac{(2b+t)}{2m}tx+\frac{x^2t^2}{m}+O(1/m^2)\Big)e^{-xt}dx$$
$$=m^{-a-3/2}\Big(\Gamma(a+3/2)+\frac{\Gamma(a+7/2)}{m}-\Gamma(a+5/2)\frac{(2b+3)}{m}+O(1/m^2)\Big)$$
and does not depends on $t$ (up to the exponentially small terms $\sim e^{-tm}$).

As @herb steinberg mentioned above, the integrals are dominated by the value of $x$ near zero, and the limit of the ratio $\frac{(1)}{(2)}$ is equal to 1.